# Get prepend() dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table generated in a backend.  My task is to wrap text in each header column and add it to each body column cells by using `.html()` and `.prepend()`.  It works as expected (you will see text in green).

Problem: Tables are generated in a backend, sometimes a table has 3 columns, sometimes 4 columns or more!  How to write my Jquery dynamically in order to work on each table.

Please give me a hand.  Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstHead = $("table thead tr th:first-child").html();
  var firstBodyCode = $("<span></span>").text(firstHead);
  $('table tbody tr td:first-child').prepend(firstBodyCode);

  var secondHead = $("table thead tr th:nth-child(2)").html();
  var secondBodyCode = $("<span></span>").text(secondHead);
  $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').prepend(secondBodyCode);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray
}

span {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to iterate over all the columns.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table thead tr th").each(function(i) {
    let bodyCode = $("<span>", {
      text: $(this).text()
    });
    $(`table tbody tr td:nth-child(${i+1})`).prepend(bodyCode);
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray
}

span {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Barmar so much!  Your code works so well

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I am wondering why it doesn't work if I add a class name inside `<span>  like this `let bodyCode = $("<span class='myClass'>" ` .  It won't prepend a text.

Comment: That should work, too. The syntax I use is safer because you don't have to worry about special characters. If you want to set the class, add that as a property: `"class": "myClass"`

Comment: Hi @Barmar, Thank you, class works well!  Your code is very short, dynamic and very clever! Please give me a chance to understand more your code.  I wonder why we set only an open '<span>', but after we run, it automatically adds a close `</span>` .  Why should we have a property `text: ...` here?  And I try without a $ sign here `td:nth-child(${i+1}` it doesn't work out!  I wonder why?

Comment: The `text:` property is equivalent to calling `.text(...)` after creating the element.